# Visual Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Visual Studio 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012)

I was told Visual studio would not work for Ubuntu.  However, after searching to see if I can get notepad++ to work on a new install of Ubuntu 12.04 I found something called wine.  After some more reading I am under the impression wine is a windows installer for Ubuntu?  Can someone verify this?  I am also to presume that I could install Visual Studio on Ubuntu via wine?

[reference](http://sqlandplsql.com/2012/06/11/install-notepad-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: If you're not doing .net-specific development (ie - you're doing something more like PHP, JavaScript, Java, etc), you'll probably be better off using one of the many natively-available tools that are available to you, such as Gedit (with plugins), Kate, Sublime Text, or Eclipse.

Comment: yes I did install netbeans already.  I havent searched for eclipse yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a Windows Installer.. it's a compatibility layer. It is true that you can install Windows software on Ubuntu through Wine, but results may vary.

WineHQ has a database of apps that may or may not work.

Here is the entry for Visual Studio..
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892

Unfortunately, most versions get a "garbage" rating, meaning that they won't work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Similar questions have been asked a few times before here:

[How can I install Visual Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012)

[C# on ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223229/c-on-ubuntu-12-04)

The bottom line, is that it's going to be very difficult to get Visual Studio working on Ubuntu.  Which .Net language are you trying to use?

If you want to use C#, there are alternative IDEs for that.  You will have a much easier time getting the [MonoDevelop IDE](http://monodevelop.com/) to install properly (vs. Visual Studio) and that will allow you to write C# applications on Ubuntu.

Comment: Completely off-topic, but I like your rep count. :P

Comment: @Gladen I know right?!?!  I just had my friends at work come over to look at my 1337 r3p.